# Undefined value is being populated when i try to access javascript array

Tags: javascript

The alert alert(document.inform.cid); is coming as undefined

```
 <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var interval = window.setInterval(iterate, 5000);
    function iterate() {
    var myStringArray = ["user1", "user2"];
       iterate.arr = iterate.arr || myStringArray.slice(0);

        //if it still has elements left
        if(iterate.arr.length > 0) {
            document.inform.cid = iterate.arr.pop(); //remove the top one
            alert(document.inform.cid);
            document.inform.pwd = "xxxxxxxx";
            document.inform.target = iterate.arr.length; // a different target each time - length of the arr
            document.inform.submit();
        } else {
            window.clearInterval(interval); //no more left cancel it
        }
    };

    </script>
     </head>
     <body >
      <form name="inform"   target="newWin" action="https://www.google.co.in/">
     <input type="hidden" name="throttle" value="999" />
     <input type="text" name="cid"  />
     <input type="text" name="pw"  />
        <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="iterate()">
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Forgetting `.value` for all nodes in your javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
>  document.inform.cid = iterate.arr.pop();
```

note that `document.inform.cid` is a reference to a DOM input element, and `iterate.arr.pop()` is a string value. So the assignment is incompatible.

I think you mean:

```
 document.inform.cid.value = iterate.arr.pop();

 --------------------^^^^^
```

That may have been more obvious if you'd use the more formal:

```
 document.forms['inform'].elements['cid'].value ...
```